# How to modify your $PATH on unix?

Tags: unix

I used `PATH = /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/:$PATH`

But still my programs refuse to search in the given dir first. Do I need to do something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use: `export PATH=.....` to make the PATH variable available as an environment variable to programs started from shell. Make sure that your programs are started from the same shell in which you are exporting the PATH variable. Please note that there is no space before and after `=`.

In your case, use:

```
export PATH=/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/:$PATH
```

Comment: Ok, will try. But just out of a unix newbie curiosity. What's the difference. echo $PATH shows me I have the right..

Comment: if a variable is not exported it exists only in your shell and not in the programs you are starting from that shell. If you export it, it will be part of the environment variables and it will be inherited by all programs started from your shell.

Answer (score 0):

Add it to `~/.profile` for permanent (`~` is your $HOME).